# C++ "Hello World" program that calls hello.py to output the string?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I want to learn how to execute Python programs from within C++ code. How is this done, for example using the simplest of C++ and Python programs as shown below (the classic "Hello World" programs)? For now I want to learn how to do this on my Windows 10 desktop where I do have Visual Studio and can code and execute C/C++/Python; a longer term goal will be to do this sort of thing on a Raspberry Pi. Any help greatly appreciated. I have Python 3 installed on my Windows 10 PC.

```
// C++ Program
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    // How can the above line of code be changed so that 
    // 'Hello World!' is output using a call to a simple
    // hello.py program ?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would you like to use the CPython API, or are you willing to use a C++ library such as pybind11?

Comment: I assume you want to start the python interpreter and have it execute the script? Most simple way is using [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function, providing the entire command line to it. If you want to communicate with the command interpreter [`popen`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-160) might be of interest or you go down directly to windows API (not too convenient): [`CreateProcess`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa).

Comment: In order to  allow for more focused answers, can you de-emphasize the Raspberry Pi portion of the question, and perhaps make it the focus of a new question later?

Comment: @Aconcagua: yes, start the python interpreter and have it print out "Hello World". But.... though I have never done it, I think python programs can be converted to executables and that would be interest to also try, that is have the C++ program run an executable.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you'll need to make sure the relevant Python include directories and libraries are linked against your C++ project. First, find where Python is installed on your system; for me it is in `C:\Python39` but you may have to go on a bit of a wild goose chase if Windows has decided to bury it somewhere else.

Make sure that your target architecture matches the Python architecture; this *almost certainly* means making sure that you set the dropdown next to the big friendly `Local Windows Debugger` button to `x64`.

Next, in your Visual Studio project, lets say it's named `PythonTestProject`, you'll need to right click on the project name in the Solution Explorer window and click properties. Then navigate to `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General` and add the directory `C:\Python39\include` to the `Addition include directories` field, of course changing the path prefix to wherever you installation is. Then navigate to `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input` and prepend `C:\Python39\libs\python3.lib;` (note the semicolon) to the `Additional dependencies` field. Your project is now good to be run against Python.

To run a simple file, you need the `PyRun_SimpleFile` (the simple here doesn't actually refer to how complicated the code in the file is, as much as the simple calling convention) which is provided in `Python.h`. You'll also need to initialize the interpreter before calling this function, and optionally clean it up afterwards although this will be done automatically when your program ends. So something like this:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize the Python interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Open a script and run it
    const char* filename = "hello.py";
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(f, filename);

    // Clean up any memory and state allocated by the Python interpreter
    fclose(f);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

should do the trick. Make sure that `hello.py` is in the same directory as the rest of the source files in your project, hit that big friendly debug button and it should run you file.

Hope this gets you on the right track :). I do strongly recommend looking into a C++ library such as [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) which will make your life much (much much) easier than dealing directly with the C API. If you want to just do simple things like this though, then it is not worth the trouble; the functions described in the [C API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html) can do a lot of simple tasks very easily.

Comment: Dominic, thank you! I am going to try that and see if I can make it happen. Snowstorm coming here late tomorrow so I will have some indoor snowbound time to kill to as to play with this project!

Comment: When using python3.lib, try to use release mode.

Answer (score -1):

On C/C++, you can use the system command to execute any shell command. That would allow you to use just about any other language, including Python, Node.js, C#...
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170)

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    system("echo hello world");
}
```

Comment: That looks all too simple lol but if it works that would be amazing as a simple solution. I will play with that code, thank you!